# Does forEach create a deep copy of array before looping?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is an example

```
arr1 = [{ b: 2 }, { a: 1 }] // an array with 2 elements

arr1.forEach(function (element, index, array) {

    console.log(element);
    console.log('of');
    console.log(array);
    console.log('');


    arr1.push({ c: 3 });
});

console.log(arr1);
```

**Result**

```
{ b: 2 }
of
[ { b: 2 }, { a: 1 } ]

{ a: 1 }
of
[ { b: 2 }, { a: 1 }, { c: 3 } ]

[ { b: 2 }, { a: 1 }, { c: 3 }, { c: 3 } ]
```

In above example I am traversing an array and adding more values to it and they are getting added in the original one while looping

Does `forEach`use a different array to loop?

Comment: [ECMAScript 2015, 22.1.3.10 Array.prototype.forEach ( callbackfn )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) -> Steps 3 and 8. The number of elements to visit is determined before the first call of `callbackfn` and not updated afterwards

Comment: In `forEach` and in (possibly all) other array methods the index variable is not mutable and relies on the conditions the moment the method is invoked. Such as it will start from 0 and will increment up until the length of the array the moment it is invoked. It's fixed and even if you try to modify it in your callback like advancing, retarding or breaking in the middle... you can not unless you throw an exception. Plus there is no standard JS functionality to clone a deep copy of an object whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not use a different array, as you can see, that when you `console.log(array);`, you will still see the new elements, even though you pushed them onto `arr1`. 
So we know that `array` and `arr1` point to the same Array.

However what `forEach` does, atleast according to the [polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill), is this:

Before iterating through it, it will extract the length of the Array, and only then start iterating. So if the length of the array changes inside the function you pass to `forEach`, the iteration will not change.

```
// 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get() internal
// method of O with the argument "length".
// 3. Let len be toUint32(lenValue).
var len = O.length >>> 0;



// 6. Let k be 0
k = 0;

// 7. Repeat, while k < len
while (k < len) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not create any copy of array.
The reference to the original array is passed to the array argument of the forEach function.
Kindly follow below link.
http://jkoder.com/foreach-method-in-arrays-functional-programming-in-javascript-part-3/

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.